# Return Statements in a Finite State Machine

Tags: java, return, state-machine

Could anyone tell me what purpose a return statement in a Finite State Machine's state serves? For example I have this code for a soccer player's state:

```
public class ChaseBall extends State<FieldPlayer> {

    private static ChaseBall instance = new ChaseBall();

    private ChaseBall() {
    }

    //this is a singleton
    public static ChaseBall Instance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void Enter(FieldPlayer player) {
        player.Steering().SeekOn();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void Execute(FieldPlayer player) {
        //if the ball is within kicking range the player changes state to KickBall.
        if (player.BallWithinKickingRange() && player.isReadyForNextKick()) {
            player.GetFSM().ChangeState(KickBall.Instance());
            return;
        }

        //if the player is the closest player to the ball then he should keep
        //chasing it
        if (player.isClosestTeamMemberToBall()) {
            player.Steering().SetTarget(player.Ball().Pos());

            return;
        }

        //if the player is not closest to the ball anymore, he should return back
        //to his home region and wait for another opportunity
        player.GetFSM().ChangeState(ReturnToHomeRegion.Instance());
    }

    @Override
    public void Exit(FieldPlayer player) {
        player.Steering().SeekOff();
    }
}
```

I was wondering if someone could explain what purpose the the return keywords in the first two if statements of the Execute() method serve?
Thanks

Comment: it's just exiting the function. If you know the state and its transition, no need to check other states/transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it's mainly a formatting alternative to a series of else if clauses. It is logically equivalent to

```
if (<condition>) {
    <code>
} else if (<condition>) {
    <code>
} else {
    <code>
}
```